# Im trying to import an Excel file using Maatwebsite on Laravel with mapping and with foreign key

Tags: excel, laravel, import, mapping, key

This is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Role;
use App\Profile;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Imports\UsersImport;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function import() 
    {


        Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('select_file'));
        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');

}



}
```

This is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use eloq;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['id','user_id','firstName','middleName','surName','bday','birthPlace','phone','address','zipcode','photo',];

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {

        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['bday'])->age;
    }

    public function users(){
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }
}
```

This is my UserImports

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Profile;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;

class UsersImport implements WithMappedCells, ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function mapping(): array
    {
        return [
            'surName'  => 'D10',
            'firstName' => 'D11',
            'middleName' => 'D12',
            'email'=> 'I34',
        ];
    }


    public function model(array $row)
    {

        $user =User::where("email", "like", "%".$row['email']."%")->first();
        $row['user_id'] = $user->id;



    return new Profile([

            'surName' => $row['surName'],
            'firstName' => $row['firstName'],
            'middleName'=> $row['middleName'],
            'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
        ]);
}



}
```

And my Excel file
[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNjMz.png)

So my first problem was with the foreign key but i got it using what is on my UserImports but now Im getting an error which is SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'surName' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`surName`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, 1, 2020-06-03 13:50:24, 2020-06-03 13:50:24))

But when I removed the user_id 
[UserImports2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o810l.png)

Im getting this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`deped`.`profiles`, CONSTRAINT `profiles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`surName`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Leano, Ramir , Inluban, 2020-06-03 13:52:35, 2020-06-03 13:52:35))

So I know its getting values from the Excel file but now it doesnt have a foreign key

EDIT: I tried to null the values in my database to check if its saving and it is but now my problem is that its looping for some reason
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9aHJ.png)

I havent used any for loops or any loops

Comment: does will it work for you?
protected $guarded = []
Add in your UserImport Model,

Comment: Please check the EDIT, cause I checked it with my database and its saving but its saving other data that are null

Comment: your `user_id` is either `null` or you are trying to create multiple profiles for each user

Comment: Well i already have my user_id, that is done. Will try to check if it is creating multiple profiles

Comment: Please don't post your sources as images.

Comment: Sorry about that, its my first time asking a question but I have edited it already